# Testing wheter an email is sent from an external system in C#

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, email

we are interacting with an external mailing service. To be able to run an effective end to end testing, we'd like to be able to check if an email has been effectively received.

We can choose the recipient email address, but the external system is basically black box.
What's the most effective strategy to be able to get and manipulate that e-mail in C#?

Thanks a lot.

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these libraries:

- [csharpmail](http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/) (open source)
- [Mail.dll](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/) (commercial)
- [Pop3MailClient](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.aspx) (open source, old but effective)
- [OpenPop.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) (open source)

[csharpmail](http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/)'s usage seems very straightforward

```
//Receive mail
Pop3Client cl = new Pop3Client();
cl.ServerName = "your server name";
cl.UserName = "your name";
cl.Password = "pass";
cl.Ssl = false;
if (cl.Authenticate() == true)
{
    Int32 MailIndex = 1;
    Pop3Message mg = cl.GetMessage(MailIndex);
    String mailTo = mg.To;
    String mailCc = mg.Cc;
    String title = mg.Subject;
    String bodyText = mg.BodyText;
    //Save Image to your local hard disk
    foreach(Pop3Content ct in mg.Contents)
    {
        String filePath = "C:\MyFolder\" + ct.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        ct.DecodeData(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let's try it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need to check a POP3 mailbox.  Out of the box, the .NET framework does not support POP3, you'll need a 3rd party library, or roll your own.  I personally like using Dart's library for POP3, although it is commericial.

http://www.powertcp.com/ptmlnet.aspx

Comment: I Think you're on spot, but a commercial tool would make things slower in some ways. Which is bizarre, by the way. Buying the tool would probably need approval... Thanks a lot.